# How can I see the compile error-code number in Visual Studio Error List view?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2010

In previous versions of Visual Studio I remember I saw the error code/number in the Error List View. I may have that confused with C++ though. To see the actual compile error number I need to save and compile the project and then check the Output-window.

It's nothing but a convenience to see the actual error number at once and it makes it easier to do a Google search for it.  Below is a screenshot of [error code CS1002](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8b47kkwz%28v=vs.90%29.aspx).

**Anybody any idea how to magically show the compile time error numbers again?**

[image]

PS: likewise, it would be great if hitting F1 in that same window would bring me to the error description page on MSDN as opposed to the useless "how to use the Error Window" page.

Comment: You mean to say Error Code number?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am afraid you can't see the information in the "Error List" window. What you can do is to open "Output" windows (you find it in "View" menu or press <kbd>Ctrl+W</kbd>,<kbd>O</kbd>. The output will be not in the table form, but you will nevertheless see the information which you need:

[image]

[image]

Comment: Actually, I already described this workaround in my question, third sentence, but nevertheless thanks for making it clearer to other readers of this thread ;) (+1 for that).

Comment: This also works for warnings, even with MSBuild output verbosity set to 'Minimal'. (Tools -> Options -> Project -> Build and Run -> ...)

Answer (score 3):

Visual Studio 2015 has this feature:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

As of Visual Studio 2010 there's no such feature in Visual Studio Error List.

The following is the closest official reply I could find from Microsoft:

> ... For the moment you can obtain the error number by either looking at
>   the error in the output window or by hitting F1 on the task list
>   (which will navigate to the appropriate help topic which contains the
>   error #).

See [this](http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/89646/show-error-code-number-in-error-list) and [this](http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/90889/compiler-errors-should-be-indicated-in-the-description-in-the-error-list) old suggestions on [Microsoft Connect](http://connect.microsoft.com/).

Comment: The Task List window no longer contains the errors, that wat up to VS 2008 only. Hitting F1 when having focus on the Error List item works for VB.NET (brings you right to the MSDN error page), but **does not** work with C#.NET (which is probably why the [default link you're brought to](http://msdn.microsoft.com/query/dev10.query?appId=Dev10IDEF1&l=EN-US&k=k%28CS1525%29;k%28VS.ERRORLIST%29;k%28SOLUTIONITEMSPROJECT%29;k%28SOLUTIONITEMSPROJECT%29;k%28TargetFrameworkMoniker-%22.NETFRAMEWORK%2cVERSION%3dV4.0%22%29;k%28DevLang-CSHARP%29&rd=true) has 3 out of 94 useful votes). Beats me... :S

Comment: F1 does work for me with C#. Then again, I've installed [Local Help Viewer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg294176.aspx)